# Is it possible to browserify the "tedious" module so that the nodejs program can be run in the browser?

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database, browserify

I'm a beginner to Node.js and I'm currently building a Node.js program that accesses and queries a Microsoft Azure SQL database with the "tedious" module (see code below) and puts the data onto a html webpage.  I want to run this code in a browser so I used browserify to bundle the modules together.  However, when this code is run in Google Chrome, the following error is returned: require is not defined.  Is there a fix? Is it even possible to use the tedious module in Chrome?  If it isn't possible, do I need to use an intermediate server between the Node.js application and the webpage?

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
var config = {  
    userName: 'hackmatch',  
    password: 'hackvalley123!',  
    server: 'hackmatch.database.windows.net',  
    options: {encrypt: true, database: 'AdventureWorks'}  
};  
var connection = new Connection(config);  
connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
    // If no error, then good to proceed.  
    console.log("Connected");  
});  

var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
```

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: `require is not defined` sounds more like a problem with Browserify (or how you're using it) than with any individual module you're using. Do you still get these errors if, instead of the `tedious` module, you try to require some other module?

Comment: I just tested the require with express and it still didn't work (same error).  It's probably something to do with the way i'm using browserify

Comment: Are you calling `require` outside of your bundle JS file?

Comment: See also [Is nodejs core module portabe on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44123916/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This module can only be used in Node.

tedious depends on the node.js `net` module to make a connection to the database server. This module has no equivalent on the browser, as web pages cannot make arbitrary network connections.

Even if it were possible to use this module in the browser, it'd be a terrible idea. You'd be allowing anyone on your web site to connect directly to your SQL server and run SQL queries. [This can only end badly.](https://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?noseen=0&threadid=2803713&pagenumber=258#post398884189)